# How can I use polars.when based on whether a column name is None?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a python function which takes a polars dataframe, a column name and a default value. The function will return a polars series (with length the same as the number of rows of the dataframe) based on the column name and default value.

- When the column name is None, just return a series of default values.
- When the column name is not None, return that column from dataframe as a series.

And, I want to achieve this with just oneline polars expression.

Below is an example for better illustration.

The function I want has the following signature.

```
import polars as pl

def f(df, colname=None, value=0):
    pass
```

And below are the behaviors I want to have.

```
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4]})

>>> f(df)
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [i64]
[
        0
        0
        0
]

>>> f(df, "a")
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [i64]
[
        1
        2
        3
]
```

This is what I tried, basically use polars.when.

```
def f(df, colname=None, value=0):
    return df.select(pl.when(colname is None).then(pl.lit(value)).otherwise(pl.col(colname))).to_series()
```

But the code errors out when colname is None, with the error message: **TypeError: argument 'name': 'NoneType' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'**.

Another problem is that the code below runs successfully, but it returns a dataframe with shape (1, 1),

```
>>> colname = None
>>> value = 0
>>> df.select(pl.when(colname is None).then(pl.lit(value)).otherwise(100))
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ literal │
│ ---     │
│ i32     │
╞═════════╡
│ 0       │
└─────────┘
```

the result I want is a dataframe with shape (3, 1), e.g.,

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ literal │
│ ---     │
│ i32     │
╞═════════╡
│ 0       │
│ 0       │
│ 0       │
└─────────┘
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't implement the if/else logic in Python?

```
def f(df, colname=None, value=0):
    if colname is None:
       series = pl.Series().extend_constant(value, df.height)
    else:
       series = df.get_column(colname)
    return series
```

Comment: I want to plug such a potential oneline expression into a select clause together with other polars expressions. And, I think using pure polars expressions will be faster?

Comment: I see. I suppose you could do something like: `df.select(pl.lit(value).repeat_by(df.height).flatten() if colname is None else colname)`

Comment: Thanks. Is the if here fine in terms of speed? I read from the doc that as long as we have python code, the process will be slowed down quite a lot. Also, does it mean there is no way to use polars.when?

Comment: The mentions of "python code"/slowdowns are referring to the use of `.apply()` instead of using expressions - not in a case like this.

Comment: Got it. What if the function in apply is also all of polars expressions code? Will we still have the slowness?

Comment: I'm not sure how `.apply()` would contain polars expressions? You would [use expressions instead of `.apply()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75351869)

Comment: I have an use case where if certain conditions are met, then no need to use other third-party functions, but if not, then delegate to other packages. So, that's why I am considering this, about how can I make the most use of polars.

Comment: Hm, okay - perhaps if you post a full example of what you're actually doing people can give you a better answer. (Maybe it should be a new question?)